# Questions about how to study or how to teach

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

Are questions about how to study computer science on-topic? Are questions about how to teach computer science on-topic?

For example, “How can I calculate this property of a graph?”, “How can I prove that this graph algorithm terminates?” and “What is the asymptotic space complexity of this graph algorithm?” are unambiguously on-topic. (Under all my broad question formats, imagine a specific, answerable question.) What about “How can I motivate the importance of this graph algorithm in my course?”, ”What is a good example to illustrate this graph algorithm in my course?“, or “I'd like to know more about this kind of graph algorithm but my textbook doesn't have any references, where can I go next?”

Comment: Perhaps [cseducators.se] might be a more suitable site?

Comment: @AndrewT. I think this site has contributor from diverse backgrounds, so I think this is much a suitable choice

Comment: While we should be mindful of overlaps with [cseducators.SE] and [academia.SE], I think that, yes, questions about didactics are very much ontopic -- as long as they call for CS (teaching) expertise. General pedagogy questions shouldn't be asked here.